# How to delete GitHub blame history?

Tags: github, version-control, blame, git-blame

I'd like to delete the GitHub blame history that GitHub shows (tracking all changes made)

I am aware of how to how to roll back changes, but I am not trying to roll back any changes I have made, I am simply trying to delete this *history* of the changes.

Obviously, I *do* own the repository that I will be operating on (and am the sole owner)

Comment: I suppose you could force-push a commit that squashes everything in existence down to one commit.

Comment: `git blame` is just one command that interacts with history in git. The history is just history, not "blame history".

Answer (score 1):

If this is for *all* files of your GitHub repository, the simplest way would be to:

- initialize a new local repository
- add files from the original repo
- add as remote the original repo GitHub URL
- force push

That is:

```
git clone https://github.com/me/myrepo
git init myrepo2
cd repo2
git --work-tree=../myrepo add .
git checkout @ -- .
git commit -m "Import myrepo"
git remote add origin https://github.com/me/myrepo
git push --force -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try